# Transfer Health App Data to Computer

Tags: ios, data, health.app

Is there a way to transfer the step data (ideally, total steps per day) from my iPhone to my computer?

Thanks!

Comment: There must be an app for that :)

Comment: The app is Q S Access https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/qs-access/id920297614?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10 in the Health app

Hit the profile (head icon) in the top right corner.

At the bottom of your profile is Export Health Data. Touching that brings up a dialog and eventually the normal sharing choice e.g. Message, Mail etc

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this link, for Excel and R:
http://www.ryanpraski.com/apple-health-data-how-to-export-analyze-visualize-guide/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review